# c# Parallel Programming, Parallel.for throwing null reference error in Epplus

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation, parallel-processing, epplus

I am new to parallel programming.I have a requirement to Upload a data into database.Before uploading,it involve in three process,

1.Data need to be validated.

2.It need to be Converted into List.

3.Finally it will be Converted in to another Type.i.e Mapping

So for this process i used parallel programming.Validation has separate method and We have separate method for converting the excel in to list.This validation method is called from Converting method.This process should happened Concurrently.it works fine in normal for loop.But not in Parallel.for.For same file,at some case validation is successfully happened and at some case it shows error as

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object

This error is coming only in validation method.Since data is available.

Below i have the parallel code

```
Parallel.For(2, BelieversWorkSheet.Dimension.End.Row, new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = BelieversWorkSheet.Dimension.End.Row },rowIterator => 
{
var BelieverCSVs = new BelieversSignupUploadDetails();
if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(BelieversWorkSheet.Cells[rowIterator, 1]?.Value?.ToString()) || !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(BelieversWorkSheet.Cells[rowIterator, 2]?.Value?.ToString()) || !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(BelieversWorkSheet.Cells[rowIterator, 3]?.Value?.ToString()) || !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(BelieversWorkSheet.Cells[rowIterator, 4]?.Value?.ToString()))
    {
    var SingeRowValidationSummary = RequiredValidationForARow(BelieversWorkSheet.Cells[rowIterator, 1, rowIterator, 4], rowIterator, BelieversWorkSheet);//Validating Method is called
    if (SingeRowValidationSummary.Count==0|| SingeRowValidationSummary==null)//add && decimal.TryParse(BelieversWorkSheet.ToString(), out Stand) && decimal.TryParse(E.ToString(), out Express)
    {
    BelieverCSVs.FirstName = BelieversWorkSheet.Cells[rowIterator, 1].Value.ToString();
    BelieverCSVs.MiddleName = BelieversWorkSheet.Cells[rowIterator, 2].Value.ToString();
    BelieverCSVs.LastName = BelieversWorkSheet.Cells[rowIterator, 3].Value.ToString();
    BelieverCSVs.DOB = DateTime.Parse(BelieversWorkSheet.Cells[rowIterator, 4].Value.ToString());
    Believers.Add(BelieverCSVs);
    }
    else
    {
    ValidationSummaryForSingle.AddRange(SingeRowValidationSummary);
    }
    }
    });
```

Below is the validation method where error occurred.

```
 private List<string> RequiredValidationForARow(ExcelRangeBase CurrentRow,int rowstart,ExcelWorksheet IndexFind)
    {
List<string> ValidationMessage=new List<string>();
Regex regex = new Regex(@"^(?!\.)(""([^""\r\\]|\\[""\r\\])*""|"+ @"([-a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~]|(?<!\.)\.)*)(?<!\.)"+ @"@[a-z0-9][\w\.-]*[a-z0-9]\.[a-z][a-z\.]*[a-z]$");
if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(((object[,])CurrentRow?.Value)[0, 0]?.ToString()))
ValidationMessage.Add( "First Name in row\t"+ IndexFind.Cells[rowstart, 1].ToString() +" is Missing" );
if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(((object[,])CurrentRow?.Value)[0, 2]?.ToString()))
ValidationMessage.Add("Last Name in row\t"+ IndexFind.Cells[rowstart, 3].ToString()+" is Missing");
if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(((object[,])CurrentRow?.Value)[0, 5]?.ToString()))
ValidationMessage.Add("Primary Email in row \t" + IndexFind.Cells[rowstart, 4].ToString() + " is Missing" );
else
if (!regex.IsMatch(((object[,])CurrentRow?.Value)[0, 4]?.ToString()))
ValidationMessage.Add("Primary Email in row \t" + IndexFind.Cells[rowstart, 4].ToString() + " is invalid");
return ValidationMessage;
}
```

Note-this error is not coming all time.if i am tring to upload same file for 10 times with same data,it showing this error for 4 time

Can any one help on this

Thanks in advance

Comment: First thing you should ask yourself, do you really need this to be parallel? How is the performance for a normal for loop?

Comment: If they want to upload 1000 and more records tomorrow.They should not wait for long time to do validation.so i thing parallel programming is the good choose for that and processing will also reduced.

Answer (score 0):

EPPlus isn't thread-safe. Doesn't claim to be. You cannot just access a resource in parallel if it wasn't specifically built for it. Grab all your data from Excel in one sequential go *and then* do what you want to do in parallel.

Comment: Thank you @nvoigt.i will try and let you know